# Eigen SparseMatrix reserve nnz

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I was wondering if the `reserve` method in *Eigen* does also allocate memory for the  **outer indices** and **inner indices** (in a 3-CSC case.)

That means if I do

```
n = 1000
SparseMatrix<float> A;
A.reserve(n)
```

then

- allocate `n` memory for **data**
- allocate `n` memory for **inner indices**
- allocate `n+1` memory for **outer indices** (worst-case and a-priori not known)

The documentation says only

> ```
> void Eigen::SparseMatrix<...>::reserve    (Index reserveSize)
> ```
>
> Preallocates reserveSize non zeros.
>
> Precondition: the matrix must be in compressed mode.

---

Can anyone clarify this? Or tell something about the reservation policy? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the sizes of the matrix are supposed to be rather static, so `reserve(n)` allocates space for non-zeros only. If the dimension are unknown, you can start with an upper bound:

```
SparseMatrix<float> A(n,n);
```

reserve, e.g.:

```
A.reserve(10*n);
```

and once you're done and that you know the final size, shrink it:

```
A.conservativeResize(rows,cols);
```

Comment: so that means if I know the dimensions in the beginning say `SparseMatrix<float> A(m, m); A.reserve(n);` then **inner indices** and **data** capture `n` memory and **outer indices** captures `m+1` memory?

Comment: The first part is true, but not the last one: memory for outer indices is allocated and initialized by the A(m,m) constructor. `reserve` does nothing with respected to outer indices.

Comment: great thanks. perhaps you should edit & include that in your answer.